# Each character in text is cut off

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside, pyqtgraph, pyside6

When trying to plot labels in my application, the right side of each character in the text is cut off by a few pixels. Disabling opengl seems to fix the issue but I need opengl enabled for the application. Setting windows scaling to 125% seems to minimize/make this clipping issue go away, but there must be a better solution to this.[Each character in the text is cut off on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unsWg.png)

Using pyside6 6.3.1, pyopengl 3.1.6, pyqtgraph 0.12.4

```
import os
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import GraphicsLayoutWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QPointF

class PlotCanvas(GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.setConfigOption("antialias", True)
        pg.setConfigOption("useOpenGL", True)
        pg.setConfigOption("enableExperimental", False)
        pg.setConfigOption("background", "w")
        pg.setConfigOption("foreground", "k")
        super().__init__()

        self.mainplot = self.addPlot()
        self.setup_fig()


    def setup_fig(self):
        """ Setup an initial plot.
        """
        self.mainplot.setRange(
            xRange=(-10, 1000), yRange=(-10, 2500), disableAutoRange=True
        )
        self.mainplot.setLabel("left", "Money", units="$")
        self.mainplot.setLabel("bottom", "Time", units="s")

        self.mousept = pg.TextItem(anchor=(0, 0), border=None)
        self.mainplot.addItem(self.mousept)

        pg.SignalProxy(
            self.mainplot.scene().sigMouseMoved,
            rateLimit=30,
            slot=self.mouse_moved_update,
        )
        self.mainplot.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouse_moved_update)

    def mouse_moved_update(self, evt):
        """Show coordinate by the mousepointer and update on movements.
        """
        mouse_point = self.mainplot.vb.mapSceneToView(evt)
        plot_point = self.mainplot.vb.mapSceneToView(QPointF(evt.x() + 15, evt.y()))

        self.mousept.setHtml(
            "<span style='font-size: 10pt; color: %s; border-style: solid'>"
            "x:%0.1f, y:%0.1f</span>" % ('black', mouse_point.x(), mouse_point.y())
        )
        self.mousept.setPos(plot_point.x(), plot_point.y())


def main():
    os.environ["QT_ENABLE_HIGHDPI_SCALING"] = "1"
    os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    QApplication.setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(Qt.HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy.PassThrough)
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)

    app = QApplication([])
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(PlotCanvas())
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Oh, and I am using pyside6, and pyopengl 3.1.6

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Yup, I just edited in the code, running it with python should reflect the problem I'm seeing

Comment: I cannot reproduce with Qt 6.2.2 (PyQt, not PySide, but that shouldn't change) on Linux. Btw, as far as I know, `AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` is not required anymore on Qt6, and `AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps` is deprecated. Also, please use the correct tags (if you're using PySide, at least include *that* tag, don't use just the PyQt tag).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! This problem is happening for me in Windows 10, it seems that the cut off text only happens for things rendered in the plot.